# Delete entries in one table where value is equal to one in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

What I want to do is something like a JOIN but not to get a result in this case: I have a table A containing

```
idx | values
```

and a table B containing

```
idx | A_idx | values
```

Now I want to delete all these rows in A where A.idx is equal to B.A_idx. Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
delete from table a
where IDX in (select a_idx from table b)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from A where A.idx in (select A_idx from B)
```